# ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/120.0.6099.130/chromedriver_win32.zip

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on selenium with python. My chrome browser version is "120.0.6099.130". Chrome for testing latest version is "120.0.6099.109". Now I have written the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

But I am getting the following error:
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/120.0.6099.130/chromedriver_win32.zip

I have tried to download chrome for testing version